# How to check distributional equality of conditional expectations

Tags: probability-theory

Let's say $X$ is a bounded real-valued RV, and that $Y, Z$ are RVs with values in the same, but arbitrary measure space. (Take for example $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ if specificity is required to make the question have an affirmative answer.)

How do you show that $E(X|Y)$ and $E(X|Z)$ have the same distribution whenever $(X, Y)$ and $(X, Z)$ have the same (joint) distributions?

Hints or full answers are appreciated.  I thought I could do this myself by looking at regular conditional probabilities, but I didn't succeed.

Comment: Which definition of conditional expectation are you using?

Comment: @Robert Israel For $F$ a sigma algebra and $X$ an $L^1$ RV we have $E(X|F)$ defined to be the a.s. unique RV such that $E(E(X|F)1_A)=E(X1_A)$ for all $A \in F$.  In our case, having $Y$ as the conditional means conditioning wrt the sigma algebra generated by $Y$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show that the distribution of $E(X|Y)$ is determined by quantities that are
determined by the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$.

Comment: Yes this was what I was trying.  Perhaps a stronger hint might help me.  For instance, I thought about looking at the fact that Regular conditional distributions for $X$ relative to $\sigma(Y)$ and $\sigma(Z)$ are both functions of $Y$ and $Z$ respectively.  Possibly different functions though.  I imagine this is where the joint distributions come in, but I don't know how.  If they were the same functions, then I would use the fundamental property of RCDs to be finished.  Thanks!

Comment: Actually I'm satisfied now thanks.